# how to change an element in an array that is defined as a method?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

```
private static int[] daysInMonth = { 31 , 28 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 };
```

I'm looking for a way to make it that if the `year % 4 == 0` then `daysInMonth[1] = 29`.

Comment: `if (year % 4 == 0) { daysInMonth[1] = 29; }`, if this is not what you want then you need to clarify what you are asking

Comment: 1) What do you mean by defining array as a method? 2) It is not quite correct to assume that leap year is defined by `year % 4  == 0`.  3) _Why_ would you need to change the value in the array?  This means that for other "invocations" you'll have to check/restore 28 days.

Answer (score 1):

While the question is not very clear, I'll attempt an answer.

What you seem to be asking is that when you access daysInMonth[1], you need it to be dynamic based on the year you are working with.

If you wish to use daysInMonth[1], then it's not possible without using lamdas or method references as the array instead of integer.

What I would instead recommend is that you access the values via an accessor method, something like this:

```
public int daysOfMonth(int year, int month) {
  if (month == 1 && year % 4 == 0) {
    return 29;
  }
  return daysInMonth[month];
}
```

Comment: `year % 4 == 0` is correct to detect a leap year in Julian calendar, while Gregorian calendar has been in use for a while.  Also this method _always_ returns the number of days in February :)

Comment: Corrected that :P

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's a leap year.  If it is, the Feb has 29 days.

```
 private static int[] daysInMonth = {31 , LocalDate.now().isLeapYear() ? 29:28 ,
                                    31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31};
```